# Why is my method returning infinity?

Tags: java

The fifteen.monthyPayment()); is returning infinity every time I run it.  I cannot figure out why.  I believe it has something to do with the years, because if I change the years value to equal a certain number, say 15, it does not return infinity.  I thought the MyLoan fifteen should change it to 15 for me.

Can any body tell me why this code is returning infinity?

```
public class MyLoan {

    // instance members
    private double amountBorrowed;
    private double yearlyRate;
    private int years;
    public double A;
    public double n = years * 12;

    // public instance method
    public MyLoan(double amt, double rt, int yrs) {
        this.amountBorrowed = amt;
        this.yearlyRate = rt;
        this.years = yrs;
    }

    public double monthlyPayment() {

        double i = (yearlyRate / 100) / 12;

        A = (amountBorrowed) * ((i * (Math.pow(1+i,n))) / ((Math.pow(1 + i, n))-1));
        return A;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double RATE15 = 5.75;
        double RATE30 = 6.25;
        double amount = 10000;
    }

    MyLoan fifteen = new MyLoan(amount, RATE15, 15);

    System.out.println(fifteen.monthlyPayment());

}
```

Comment: So where's the code  for `monthlyPayment`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Sorry about that!  This is just a snippet from a much larger block of code, and I Totally forgot to include monthlyPayment.

Comment: A = (amountBorrowed) * ((i * (Math.pow(1+i,n))) / ((Math.pow(1 + i, n))-1)); this make problem what exactly you want to do with this???

Comment: @PankajSaboo, that is a formula that computes the monthly payment.  Thats why I have it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialise `n` in the constructor.

```
this.years = yrs;
this.n = yrs * 12;
```

Otherwise it uses the default value for `years`, which is `0`.

Division by `0` is resulting in `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

Comment: Thank you!!  Appreciate the help.